# PHP коды в index.php

Tags: php

В чем проблема? Форма отправляет данные в register.php. Но денвер говорит, что не может найти такой файл. Если пхп код пишем в отдельном документе, а не вставляем в саму страничку, то нужно что-то писать там, отдельно от кода?

Код:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('noname');
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $username    = $_POST['username'];
    $login       = $_POST['login'];
    $password    = $_POST['password'];
    $password_ch = $_POST['password_ch'];
    if ($password == $password_ch) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO trash VALUES        
                ('','$username','$secname','$login','$password')") or die(mysql_error());
    } else {
        die('Passwords must be same');
    }
}
```

Comment: "Но денвер говорит что не может найти такой файл." какие права доступа у login.php?

Comment: ой...я не знаю)))а где это поправить?

Comment: "Если пхп код пишем в отдельном документе, а не вставляем в саму страничку, то нужно что то писать там?отдельно от кода?"
100 процентов что-то нужно писать =)

Не понятно, что Вы этим хотели сказать, переформулируйте, пжл.

Comment: кроме кода пхп..я же прислал код отдельного пхп документа с кодом..имел ввиду что кроме этого для работоспособности скрипта ничего не нужно?

Comment: читайте про разницу расположения файлов относительно файловой системы и относительно сервера. много интересного найдете там.   

зыж в винде не надо никакие права выставлять... к сожалению...

Comment: "Но денвер говорит что не может найти такой файл." - вывод: не используем Денвер

Comment: для WEB не забываем первым символом ставить <?php

#!/usr/bin/php - это для cli режима

Comment: а как вы отправляете? дайте код формы

Comment: код формы и конкретную ошибку, полный текст...

Comment: я так полагаю, основываясь на предыдущих вопросах, раньше ЭТО было в cgi-bin со всеми вытекающими....

Comment: Вот такая вот форма
<form method="post" action="registration.php">
    Имя: <br>
    <input type="text" name="username"SIZE="20"placeholder="Александр" required  /><br>
    Логин: <br>
    <input type="text" name="login"SIZE="20"placeholder="Koro"required /><br>
    Пароль:<br>
    <input type="password" name="password" SIZE="20"placeholder="Password" required /><br>
    Повторите пароль: <br>
    <input type="password" name="password_ch" SIZE="20"placeholder="Repeat password"  required /><br>
    <input class="regbutton" type="submit" name="register"value="Register"/>
    </form>

Comment: пишет что не может найти файл register.php после нажатия на кнопку отправки данных